# Accessing LinkedIn company's activity feed as non-admin

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm writing an application that is supposed to aggregate a company's social media platforms in one page. To do this I need to be able to access the company's activity feed.

When I signed up as a company for API access I enlisted my Application under Social Aggregation, the only permissions I was given are r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin and w_share. None of these allow access to the activity feed, outside of rw_company_admin, which only allows the administrator of the company access to the feed, not another user.

Due to the 60-day lifecycle of the OAUTH2 token I'm unable to make the API call as an administrator on the background, since permission needs to be granted by a log-in.

This is what I have access too. 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

I think I'd be able to achieve my goal with this;
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed

However, I need to be a LinkedIn partner to be able to make those API calls, and I'm not looking to access a user's entire feed. Just the feed of the company he is working for.

Answer (score 0):

Organization shares can only be retrieved if the authorized member is also an administrator of the organization.